# can someone explain how this reference function work with this perl subroutine?

Tags: perl, subroutine

this is the sub routine which i could not understand , i tried to pass some array and hash as argument but could not figure it out

```
sub List {

        my $value = shift;
        my $key = shift; 

     if (ref($value->{$key}) eq ARRAY) {

        $value->{$key}
     }
     elsif (ref($value->{$key}) eq HASH) {
        [$value->{$key}]
     }
     else { [
     ]
     }
    }
```

Comment: Judged by `ref($value->{$key})` you call this function with two scalars (`fun($s1, $s2)`), the first one being a hash _reference_ and the second a key in that hashref. I don't see how the function's returns make sense though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument is expected to be a reference to a hash.

The second argument is the key of an element of the referenced hash.

If the element's value is a reference to an array, that reference is returned.

```
my @a = ...;
my %h = { key => \@a };
List(\%h, 'key')   # Returns \@a
```

If the element's value is a reference to an hash, a reference to an array containing that hash reference is returned.

```
my %inner = ...;
my %h = { key => \%inner };
List(\%h, 'key')   # Returns [ \%inner ]
```

Otherwise, returns a reference to an empty hash

```
my %h = { };
List(\%h, 'key')   # Returns []
```